# Where was this photograph taken?

Tags: identify-this, mountains, snow

What is the location of this mountain?
[image]

View from more above:
[image]

[The source youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt7MdEZtk4U) (Since it is a live stream, the short video clip won't necessarily be shown again)

I also asked the question on the following other platforms:

[where-is-this.com](https://www.where-is-this.com/index/view/8800.html)

[reddit.com: Subreddit "wherewasthistaken"](https://www.reddit.com/r/wherewasthistaken/comments/9ffj0j/what_mountain_and_where_is_this/)

---

**EDIT:** I updated the URL for source video, since I put in the wrong URL. In the stream on the updated URL, you can actually see the video still be repeated every couple of hours.

Comment: Where did you find those pictures?

Comment: They were shown in a live stream of peaceful relaxing music. Actually it was a short drone clip (5 seconds or so).

Comment: Your best bet is probably reddit, there's a whole subredit dedicated to identifying locations from photos 
https://www.reddit.com/r/wherewasthistaken/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really about travel; it's a screen grab from an video, uncredited here, and impossible to answer absent additional details.

Comment: Precedent seems to be that this kind of question is on-topic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree, it can be, and is, but usually there are a few more clues offered and has a connection with travel, even loose. With more than a million mountains on the planet, several still frames from a video make it nearly impossible to pinpoint, even for those of us here who like the puzzler challenge.

Comment: I agree this doesn't directly have anything to do with travel, alltough the commonness of similar highly upvoted questions (also with screenshots from somewhere) baited me into thinking this is a proper thing to ask.

Comment: @RUL - did reddit manage to identify the location?

Comment: @zeocrash unfortunately not yet. And neither did where-is-this.com

Comment: @RUL could you please add links to your queries on reddit and where-is-this.com as well as the stream you got it from? I guess one link is https://www.where-is-this.com/index/view/8800.html

Comment: @mts, that's exactly the one on where is this. I will edit the question.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the youtube video?

Comment: @user13190, i can, but I don't think it is of great use, since (as mentioned) it is a live stream, meaning, the video is not necessarily shown again and the other videos seem to be from different countries: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDIKYoPaw2Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered now on where-is-this-com:

It is Podul cu Florile in Romania.

Comment: A link to the answer or the proof would be nice.

Comment: @RHA A link to the answer on where-is-this.com is already in the question. I have no idea what 'proof' you are looking for?

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that 